# Passing array of coordinate[] to a new activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to pass an array of type Coordinates (coordinate[] arrCoordinates) to another Activity class. I find it easy to pass Strings and Ints (e.g intent.putExtra("string", myString);  but I can't seem to pass an array of coordinates. 
I also tried looking into using Parcelable..but I'm not quite sure on coding it. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these situations, I have always used the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class to store global variables.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables) for more information.

A dirty hack (which I do not recommend) is to make your array a public static member of your first `Activity` class in order to easily grab a reference into your new `Activity`.